# WinForms too many handles

Tags: c#, windows, handle, system.drawing

I our production, my application caused two different exceptions:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Image(Image value)
   at Zeiss.IMT.IME.CmmUI.Tools.ToolControl.updateControls()
```

There is another exception that i suppose to have the same cause:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateCompatibleDIB(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hpal, Int32 ulWidth, Int32 ulHeight, IntPtr& ppvBits)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateBuffer(IntPtr src, Int32 offsetX, Int32 offsetY, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBuffer(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBufferInTempManager(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

At both exceptions, the windows task manager shows up a lot of handles (>8500). So the windows handle limit is reached and the application fails to allocate more memory/handles.
So far i understand the problem.
In this case i'm heavily using GDI drawing via System.Drawing. So i searched my code where graphics handles are not released - without success.

So the question is:
How can i find unreleased (native) handles???

Comment: You could use a memory profiler....I've used one with an app heavily relying on GDI+ and it found memory leaks and unreleased handles that were hard to discover looking line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use memory profile tools. For example this one: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

But are you disposing all Disposable objects? Brushes and so on..

You could post your drawing code perhaps we can see something wrong.

Perhaps there are some brushes,... that aren't disposed.

Comment: The code is huge...  
Good advice, i have to search for all IDisposable objects.  
Is there a memory profiler in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. Go Analyze>Profiling in VS2010/2012. when you choose the wizzard you can select memory sampling.

Comment: You can also consider of addin a FXCop / Code Analysis rule for IDisposable type, so the FxCop also helps you to find them

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your code and make sure you release all your disposable object when no longer needed. Pack a disposable object into a using statement.

If there are really, so many GDI handles needed, you can increase the maximum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: The number of handles is increasing the longer the application runs. So i have a leak to fix. Increasing the maximum is not an option in our production.